# Leaderboard points are not updated

Tags: java, android, google-play-services, leaderboard

I'm learning LeaderBoard from Google Play Services. First one when I call below code, my score became 1137

```
public void updateAllScore(){
            Games.getLeaderboardsClient(this, GoogleSignIn.getLastSignedInAccount(this))
                    .submitScore(getString(R.string.leaderboard_id), 1137);
    }
```

After I call same code, but score wasn't changed. Then I've changed 1137 to 1, but score wasn't changed. Score is 1137 still.

```
public void updateAllScore(){
            Games.getLeaderboardsClient(this, GoogleSignIn.getLastSignedInAccount(this))
                    .submitScore(getString(R.string.leaderboard_id), 1);
    }
```

Comment: I found answer. The answer is leaderboard shows only best score like shows best time of player. Leaderboard doesn't increase score with this code

Comment: STUPID realization of leaderboard from Play Service. In the many games the users need sum of score. There is no function of submit for each DAILY, WEEK, ALL_TIME. You can submit only one result. Why it's so stupiidddddd?????